# Oxygen Builder query custom post from a nested repeater

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, repeater

I'm using Oxygen Builder and Meta Box. I have 2 custom types :

- Portfolio items
- Technologies

Each have their own set of custom fields. Portfolio items has 1 or more technologies.

I have a first repeater that loops through the portoflio items but when I display the "custom field" "technologies" it returns an ID that probably represents the group of technologies.

I want to iterate through these technologies with another nested repeater. I'm trying to build an advanced query.

I'm starting with post_type and select "technology". it now returns all the technologies, not the specific ones to my current item. How can I achieve that?